# errors object returns undefined in formik with yup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I'm trying to make a form in react with Formik and Yup (for validation). I've made yup object shape, set initial values to formik, but still validation isn't working. formik's errors props returning undefined.

```
import React from "react";
import { Formik, Form, Field } from "formik";
import * as Yup from "yup";

const schema = Yup.object().shape({
  email: Yup.string()
    .label("Email")
    .required("Enter a valid email")
    .email()
});

class OneForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    email: ""
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Formik
          initialValues={{
            email: ""
          }}
          onSubmit={(values, actions) => {
            console.log(values);
            this.setState({
              email: values.email
            });
            setTimeout(() => {
              actions.setSubmitting(false);
              actions.resetForm();
            }, 1000);
          }}
          validationSchema={schema}
        >
          {props => {
            return (
              <Form>
                {console.log(props.errors)}

                <Field
                  type="email"
                  placeholder="Email"
                  name="email"
                  onChange={props.handleChange}
                />

                {props.errors.email && <p>{props.errors.email}</p>}
                <br />
                <button
                  disabled={props.isSubmitting}
                  type="submit"
                  onClick={props.handleSubmit}
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </Form>
            );
          }}
        </Formik>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default OneForm;
```

can anyone help me here? It seems like they have an active issue regarding this here: https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1180
But, It seems like some people also solved this issue. Any help here?

Comment: Seems to be working for me https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-perlman-q0y3d

Comment: @ksav on chrome or firefox? BTW, form is working fine, but validation isn't working. Do you see any warnings on blank submit?

Comment: The console logs `{email: "Enter a valid email"}` on empty form submission with chrome74

Comment: Doesn't that mean validation is working?